# Regular Expression in String

Tags: regex, perl

I have some information in the `xml` file. I want to find out **style** attribute values in the xml file by using `perl` script.

**xml file content:**

```
<ul type="disc">
    <li class="MsoNormal" style="line-height: normal; margin: 0in 0in 10pt; color: black; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2; tab-stops: list .5in; mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto">
        <span style="mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-bidi-font-family: 'Times New Roman'"><font size="3"><font face="Calibri">Highlight the items you want to recover.</font></font></span></li>
</ul>
```

**Perl script snippet:**

```
while ($line =~ /style="([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"/gis) {
                if ($articlenbfound == 1) {
                    $articlehits++;
                    my $thelink = $1;
                    disp_str(linktofile($dir . $name . $ext) . "   line " . $index . ": <font color=red>Article " . $articlenb . " match</font>: " . $thelink . "\n");
                }
            }
```

In this Script i am capturing Style attributes value. And need to print all the style attribute values.

Comment: could you clarify is this a question of java or peal?

Comment: please be more specific with your question. you might have to read about regular expressions first (follow a tutorial, for example).
there is not *one* regular expression for a string, but many regular expressions might match a string.

Comment: Do you know what is Regular Expression? What do you mean by "what is the Regular Expression for that String"? There's no such a thing "in the form of regular expression".

Comment: @hoijui, can we capture entire string into one regular expression? I mean like ([a-zA-z]+)... This is for word.. like this

Comment: please be more specific about what you want. Like what you mean be *Regular Expression for above String*?

Comment: a regular expression only makes sense, if there are some strings that should match it, and some strings that should not match it. of course you can use a regex like ".*" which matches everything, but that would not warrant a new question.
please read about regex first!

Comment: @Anil `while ($line =~ /style="([^"]*)"/gis)`

Comment: I edited my post with all the details. @AvinashRaj, Thanks ... It will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's XML. XML is a bad idea to parse via regular expression. The reason for this is because these XML snippets are semantically identical:

```
<ul type="disc">
  <li
      class="MsoNormal"
      style="line-height: normal; margin: 0in 0in 10pt; color: black; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2; tab-stops: list .5in; mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto">
    <span style="mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-bidi-font-family: 'Times New Roman'">
      <font size="3">
        <font face="Calibri">Highlight the items you want to recover.</font>
      </font>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And:

```
<ul
type="disc"
><li
class="MsoNormal"
style="line-height: normal; margin: 0in 0in 10pt; color: black; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2; tab-stops: list .5in; mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto"
><span
style="mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-bidi-font-family: 'Times New Roman'"
><font
size="3"
><font
face="Calibri"
>Highlight the items you want to recover.</font></font></span></li></ul>
```

And:

```
<ul type="disc"><li class="MsoNormal" style="line-height: normal; margin: 0in 0in 10pt; color: black; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2; tab-stops: list .5in; mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto"><span style="mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-bidi-font-family: 'Times New Roman'"><font size="3"><font face="Calibri">Highlight the items you want to recover.</font></font></span></li></ul>
```

So please - use a parser. Since you've tagged `perl` I'm going to include a perl solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'span' => sub { print $_ ->att('style'), "\n" }
    }
)->parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );
```

This will print - on a new line - the `style` attribute from your `span` elements. Once you've extracted this, you can turn it into key-values via splitting on `;` and using `:` as a key-value separator.

E.g.:

```
my $style =  $_ ->att('style'); 
my %styles = map { split ( ': ', $_, 2 ) } split ( '; ', $style);
print Dumper \%styles;
```

But exactly what you do is as much a question of what you're trying to accomplish.