# how to introduce line break into xml file in unix?

Tags: xml, unix, sed

I have a file like below

```
<slave><id>1</id><name>slave 1</name></slave><slave><id>2</id><name>slave 2</name></slave><slave><id>2</id><name>slave 3</name></slave><slave><id>4</id><name>slave 4</name></slave><slave><id>5</id><name>slave 5</name></slave>
```

This needs to be converted to

```
<slave><id>1</id><name>slave 1</name></slave>
<slave><id>2</id><name>slave 2</name></slave>
<slave><id>2</id><name>slave 3</name></slave>
<slave><id>4</id><name>slave 4</name></slave>
<slave><id>5</id><name>slave 5</name></slave>
```

I tried using `sed`, But it doesn't seem to work. And I have to use one line command to achieve this. Possibly `tr` or `sed`. But I could not manage to use the correct pattern.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It has the same meaning. And that `xml` is not well-formed.

Comment: Please see here for some examples of why regex based parsing of XML is a bad idea; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866688/regular-expression-in-string/30867528#30867528

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sobrique is right of course, processing xml using regexp is a terrible thing to do. So this is one terrible way to do it:

```
cat infile.xml | sed -e 's#\(</slave>\)#\1\n#g'
```

Note that you need to escape the brackets which give you the \1 match, but because of the single-quotes you don't need to escape the angle brackets. Also using hash/pound/crunch/# as the separator means you don't need to escape the forward slash either.

Now be really careful - this works for your current, specific example, but if your input file varies or might have more complicated stuff in it then using a regex is very likely to break. However if it's a one-off thing, or you have solid guarantees about what the input file will look like, it is a quick and easy hack that doesn't need particular libraries and doesn't mind if your xml is badly formed.

Comment: It's a dirty thing to do, but sometimes all you can do is roll up your sleeves and hack :/. Still - even if it does make me shudder in horror, it's a good answer (and also points out the caveats)

Comment: I also have some examples of some different ways of formatting identical XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866688/regular-expression-in-string/30867528#30867528

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions for it, that's a bad idea. XML is not a data format that's easily parsable by regex, and so you end up with all sorts of nastiness and brittle code as a result.

Reformat it using a parser.

```
perl -MXML::Twig -e 'XML::Twig -> new ('pretty_print' => 'indented_a') -> parse ( <> )->print;' yourfile.xml
```

Will reformat it for you. Assuming your XML is valid of course. But it'll take valid XML and *keep* it as valid XML.

With reference to: http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm

I usually like pretty printing as `indented_a`, `record`.

Comment: I'm very bad at perl. Could you please let me know where i should mention the file name?

Comment: Right at the end. 
`perl -MXML::Twig -e 'XML::Twig -> new ('pretty_print' => 'indented_a') -> parse ( <> )->print;' yourfile.xml`

Comment: Can't locate XML/Twig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: Do you have any other way of achiving this other than PERL?

Comment: Install the module with `cpan XML::Twig` (or use your OS package manager) and it'll work. There are other languages you could do this in, but the 'standard unix tools' don't really cover it. (You would have to install _something_)